# Human activity recognition using smartphone data set problem

Tags: bigdata, machine-learning, databases, clustering, data-mining

I'm new to this community and hopefully my question will well fit in here.
As part of my undergraduate data analytics course I have choose to do the project on human activity recognition using smartphone data sets. As far as I'm concern this topic relates to Machine Learning and Support Vector Machines. I'm not well familiar with this technologies yet so I will need some help.

I have decided to follow [this project idea](http://www.inf.ed.ac.uk/teaching/courses/dme/2014/datasets.html) (first project on the top)
The project goal is determine what activity a person is engaging in (e.g., WALKING, WALKING_UPSTAIRS, WALKING_DOWNSTAIRS, SITTING, STANDING, LAYING) from data recorded by a smartphone (Samsung Galaxy S II) on the subject's waist. Using its embedded accelerometer and gyroscope, the data includes 3-axial linear acceleration and 3-axial angular velocity at a constant rate of 50Hz.

All the data set is given in one folder with some description and feature labels. The data is divided for 'test' and 'train' files in which data is represented in this format:

```
  2.5717778e-001 -2.3285230e-002 -1.4653762e-002 -9.3840400e-001 -9.2009078e-001 -6.6768331e-001 -9.5250112e-001 -9.2524867e-001 -6.7430222e-001 -8.9408755e-001 -5.5457721e-001 -4.6622295e-001  7.1720847e-001  6.3550240e-001  7.8949666e-001 -8.7776423e-001 -9.9776606e-001 -9.9841381e-001 -9.3434525e-001 -9.7566897e-001 -9.4982365e-001 -8.3047780e-001 -1.6808416e-001 -3.7899553e-001  2.4621698e-001  5.2120364e-001 -4.8779311e-001  4.8228047e-001 -4.5462113e-002  2.1195505e-001 -1.3489443e-001  1.3085848e-001 -1.4176313e-002 -1.0597085e-001  7.3544013e-002 -1.7151642e-001  4.0062978e-002  7.6988933e-002 -4.9054573e-001 -7.0900265e-001
```

And that's only a very small sample of what the file contain.

I don't really know what this data represents and how can be interpreted. Also for analyzing, classification and clustering of the data, what tools will I need to use?
Is there any way I can put this data into excel with labels included and for example use R or python to extract sample data and work on this?

Any hints/tips would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The data set definitions are on the page here:

[Attribute Information at the bottom](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones#)

or you can see inside the ZIP folder the file named activity_labels, that has your column headings inside of it, make sure you read the README carefully, it has some good info in it. You can easily bring in a `.csv` file in R using the `read.csv` command.

For example if you name you file `samsungdata` you can open R and run this command:

```
data <- read.csv("directory/where/file/is/located/samsungdata.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Or if you are already inside of the working directory in R you can just run the following

```
data <- read.csv("samsungdata.csv", header = TRUE)
```

Where the name `data` can be changed to whatever you want to call your data set.

Comment: I see. I did study the README file, however I still can't figure out how the data it self can be read. For example, the train/X_train.txt'file represents training set (the sample data that I showed in post comes from this file).

Comment: It seems to me that the data set is rather wide, there are 561 variables per row which are listed inside of the features.txt file. I believe that is what you are referring to.

Comment: So each of the variable from 'features' file corresponds to each column in e.g 'x-test.txt' file, or Am I wrong?

Comment: That is how I am taking it. From what I could gather from the README is that is what the file contains.

Comment: @Jakubee Yes. There are 561 rows/variable names in the `features.txt` file, and 561 columns in the `X_train.txt` file, one for each variable.

Comment: Ok. I do get it now! Thanks!! But what about the data itself. What kind of analytics I can process on this? (That might be stupid question) You think I can apply this for future analysis with python, using e.g hadoop?

Comment: You can definitely use Python, I don't know if Hadoop will be necessary for files of this size, you could also use R and install the package Rattle with the following command `install.packages("rattle")` it is a good data mining package for R. In the future if you are going to be using massive data sets then for sure Hadoop will be good to know and use

Answer (score 5):

It looks like this (or very similar data set) is used for Coursera courses. Cleaning this dataset is task for [Getting and Cleaning Data](https://www.coursera.org/course/getdata), but it is also used for case study for [Exploratory Data analysis](https://class.coursera.org/exdata-002). Video from this case study is available in videos for week 4 of EDA course-ware. It might help you with starting with this data.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to me like a typical time series classification case. After cleaning and normalizing the data, you could build a simple LSTM model to learn the time series with  2 dense layers downstream to do the classification in tensorflow. Just Google time series classification and you'll get what you're looking for.