# How to prepere dataset for binary classification (anomaly detection?) on timestamped sensor data (multiple files)?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, feature-engineering, anomaly-detection, binary-classification

my goal is to make prediction (good or bad data) on sensor data. I tried a lot, but failed to shape my data to get the desired output.

scenario:

I have multiple timestamped (time as it self is not important) measurements files with each containing 1700 datapoints of 2 features. The first column is the timestamp (in ns). t0 = 1 ns after the start of the meassurement. The other two columns are the data points at that timestamp namely the depth and intensity.

Here is a header of such a file:

```
    columns = ['timestamp', 'Intensity', 'depth']
    array([[  1.        ,  79.        ,  -0.5273184 ],
           [ 14.        ,  94.        ,  -0.56211778],
           [ 29.        , 102.        ,  -0.59692583],
           [ 43.        , 109.        ,  -0.57392274],
           [ 57.        , 111.        ,  -0.55091889]])

           [1700 rows (timestamps) and 2 features])
```

A good measurement looks like that (image at the end of the post):

The x-axis represent the time-axis calulated to a length in mm. The y-axis is the depth-axis and the color represent the intensity of that datapoint.

What i have done:

1. I created a list with all my files
   `file_names_list = [file_name for file_name in os.listdir(path_for_csv_data) if file_name.endswith('.txt')]` and looped thru that list
2. In each interation of that loop i created a DataFrame and reshaped it and appeded to data_list:

   ```
    data_list = []
    for single_file_name in file_names_list:
           #create df
           pandas_data_frame = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path_for_csv_data, single_file_name), index_col=0, header=0, decimal = '.', delimiter = ';')

           #drop the timestamp because i dont need it
           pandas_data_frame.drop(columns = ['timestamp'], axis = 1, inplace = True)

           #reshape each file to (1700, 2)
           pandas_data_frame.values.reshape(-1, len(pandas_data_frame.columns)) #should be (1700, 2)

           #append all files to a list, to have all the data in one place
           data_list.append(pandas_data_frame) #shape is now (150, 1700, 2)
   ```
3. I splited my data into train and test data (used RobustScaler on train data), loaded my labels and created a sequential model:

   ```
   model = Sequential()
   model.add(Dense(100, input_shape = (1700,2), activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(Dropout(0.2))
   model.add(Dense(40, activation = 'relu'))
   model.add(Dense(1, activation = 'sigmoid'))
   model.compile(optimizer = 'adam', loss = 'mse', metrics = ['accuracy'])
   ```
4. Then a fited my data into my model but if i do so, i get a prediction of every datapoint (look image at the end of this post) in a shape of (x, 1700, 1), not on a file itself (shape of (x, 1)).

   ```
    model.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = model.predict(X_test)
   ```

My Questions:

1. What to do, to get the right output?
2. Is my way of prepering data right for such a problem? (timestamped data, NOT time series data, like predicting bitcoin price)) -> i just want to feed my model a numpy array with 1700 rows and 2 columns und want a output wether the data is good or bad.

Good data:
[image: good data]

Bad data:
[image: bad data]

y_pred - Output:
[image: y_pred]

Shapes of my X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test:
[image: shapes]

Comment: what are the shapes of X_train, X_test, y_train, y_pred? Can you print it and add it to the question?

Comment: Done, and yeah, i know that I scaled my X_test to. It's just for test purpose.

Comment: and i have forgot to mention, that i tried the shape (112, 2, 1700) for X_train ... but my y_pred is (x, 2,1) instead of (x, 1)

Comment: Have you looked at similar questions? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/features-for-time-series-classification https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/323571/how-to-classify-m-multivariate-time-series-into-k-known-categories  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/368100/trajectory-clustering-preprocessing-and-algorithms?noredirect=1&lq=1 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/3738/how-to-deal-with-time-series-which-change-in-seasonality-or-other-patterns/3764